# Skipping Checkout step in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to have the following flow in my Wordpress WooCommerce experience:

Product-->Cart-->PayPal

I want to skip the Checkout step between the Cart and PayPal - since the only option I want on my site is PayPal, the Checkout page of WooCommerce is rather redundant and silly in my case.

What do I need to do in order to make that happen?